# knockout.js observable subscriber manipulating dependencies for ko.computed

Tags: knockout.js

The following code has an `ko.computed` that is the uppercase version of `name`. The subscriber modifies `name`, but the computed observable doesn't track the change.

```
​var ViewModel = function() {
    this.name = ko.observable("Brad");
    this.nameUpper = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.name().toUpperCase();
    }, this);
};

var model = new ViewModel();
model.nameUpper.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    console.log('nameUpper changed to ' + newValue);
    this.name("Chris");
}, model);​​​

console.log('nameUpper = ' + model.nameUpper());
model.name("Stevie");
console.log('nameUpper = ' + model.nameUpper());
```

Expected output:

```
nameUpper = BRAD
nameUpper changed to STEVIE
nameUpper = CHRIS
```

Actual output:

```
nameUpper = BRAD
nameUpper changed to STEVIE
nameUpper = STEVIE
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/LPhyW/) the jsfiddle.

**Update:** It would appear this is intentional given [this line](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/blob/master/src/subscribables/subscribable.js#L42). My guess is that it's to protect programmers from accidently inducing infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

If this were allowed it would create a circular dependency, causing endless recalculation. 
'nameUpper' depends on value of 'name' and is recalculated every time 'name' changes. If you subscribe to your computed and keep modifying 'name' the subscribe event will just keep refiring.